# Is it possible to make simple tooltip by animate() function of jquery?

Tags: jquery

i want to make simple tooltip on top of a text, is there any simple jquery code to make it without any plug-in? a tooltip to be show slowly and expend from small box to bigger box.

Comment: Everything is `POSSIBLE`

Comment: Like Tushar said, if you cba to write your own code. Why not use a plugin for it?

Comment: i want to have simple code to understand it